# How do I (and should I) make additional methods on DOM objects?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, dom, prototype

I want to extend an element by a method, but I've heard it is a bad idea. Therefore I'm wondering if it is possible to make a class so that its instances have all the methods and properties of a regular element in the prototype, but instead of extending all elements in the DOM, the additional methods would only be included in the instances of that class.

Example (that doesn't work; just a concept):

```
class MyElement {
  constructor(element) {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, element);
  }

  // Only on elements I declare using this class, not on all HTMLElements
  triggerDisplay() {
    // This function is an example, all regular HTMLElement properties should work
    if (this.style.display === 'none') this.style.display = null;
    else this.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

What I want to achieve is a way to use OOP with the DOM like this:

```
// Custom class that inherits from a div element
const myCustomElement = new MyElement(document.getElementById('myDiv'));

// OOP
myCustomElement.triggerDisplay();
```

Instead of:

```
// Regular element
const myNotCustomElement = document.getElementById('myDiv');

// Functional programming
triggerDisplay(myNotCustomElement);
```

All I want is a way to properly use object-oriented programming with the DOM. Am I really bound to functional programming when working with it?

If nothing works, is this good to use this:

```
HTMLDivElement.pprototype.triggerDisplay = function() {
  if (this.style.display === 'none') this.style.display = null;
  else this.style.display = 'none';
}
```

?

Comment: See [Why is extending the DOM/built-in object prototypes a bad idea?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/104320/222246) for some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to call custom methods on an instance which alters a DOM element, it would probably make the most sense to have the class just save the DOM element as a property of the instance, and then look it up when necessary. For example:

```
class MyElement {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
  }
  triggerDisplay() {
    const { element } = this;
    if (element.style.display === 'none') element.style.display = null;
    else element.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

const myCustomElement = new MyElement(document.getElementById('myDiv'));

myCustomElement.triggerDisplay();
```

If you need to be able to directly reference element properties without going through the `.element` property, you can use prototypal inheritence to set the element as the internal prototype of the instance:

```
const customProps = {
  triggerDisplay: {
    value: function() {
      const element = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
      if (element.style.display === 'none') element.style.display = null;
      else element.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
};
const makeCustomElement = (element) => {
  return Object.create(element, customProps);
};

const myCustomElement = makeCustomElement(document.getElementById('myDiv'));

myCustomElement.triggerDisplay();
```

(if you also want to assign to properties directly on the `myCustomElement`, then use *another* `Object.create` wrapper so that assignment does not mutate the `customProps` object)

Comment: The first example works fine, but with the second one I get `Uncaught TypeError: myCustomElement.triggerDisplay is not a function`

Comment: Ah, the second argument to `Object.create` needs to be an object of *descriptors*, not just of plain properties, see edit. Yes, everything here is plain ES2015 (or earlier)

Comment: I use Babel, so ES6 support doesn't matter; I was just wondering whether the DOM inheritance stuff works well across browsers

Comment: I think I would use the first method because when you do `console.dir(myCustomElement)` on the second solution there are a lot of attributes inherited from the HTMLDivElement and all of them contain an error

Comment: Looks like they all expect a particular `this` as well, and having an internal prototype of the element doesn't cut it. If you had to, you could intercept all method calls with a Proxy instead, or iterate through the prototype chain and manually put all method names on the prototypes onto the `customProps`, but that's pretty ugly. Using the `.element` property instead like in the first snippet is a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

I would create a [custom element](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements) for this:

> With Custom Elements, web developers can create new HTML tags, beef-up existing HTML tags, or extend the components other developers have authored.

#### Case Study

Let's imagine that we need to hide some content and display it after 1000ms.

One possible implementation:

```html
<div id="msg1" style="display:none">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
```

```
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('#msg1').style.display = 'block';
}, 1000);
```

Let's add some other requirements:

- There can be one or many instances.
- Instances can be added or removed dynamically.
- Each instance can have a specific delay.
- Each instance can be programmatically displayed.

A CSS-only solution is impossible and we'll certainly end up with some non-trivial JavaScript infrastructure to manage all of this.

**What if we didn't need different actors to coordinate all of this? What if each instance could be responsible for its own business?**

This would be nice:

```html
<show-content after="10000">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</show-content>
```

```js
// `after` delay is too long, let's display it now
document.querySelector('show-content').display();
```

#### Creating `<show-content>` step by step

Creating a new HTML tag is surprisingly straightforward (we'll fill in the blanks later).

First create a class for it:

```
class ShowContent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then register it and give its tag name:

```js
//---------------------tag name ----- class
//                     |              |
//                     v              v
customElements.define('show-content', ShowContent);
```

At this stage you can compose standard HTML tags and your own:

```html
<body>
  <show-content after="1000">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </show-content>
</body>
```

Now we need to tell `ShowContent` to hide its content by default:

First we'll need to create some template for it. Why?

- We need some *encapsulated* *leak-free* styling.
- We need to define the point of entry (i.e. `<slot>`) where children will be added.

```html
<template id="show-content-template">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <slot></slot>
</template>
```

Let's add the following to the `ShowContent` constructor:

```
const tmpl = document.querySelector('#show-content-template');
const tmplContent = tmpl.content.cloneNode(true);
this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).appendChild(tmplContent);
```

*Note: the Shadow DOM is the internal DOM of your custom element.*

Please do note that your custom tags behave in the same way as any other standard tags. You can query them with CSS selectors, style them and look them up in the Dev Tools for free!

[image]

Now we need to implement support for the `after` attribute:

```
class ShowContent extends HTMLElement {
  // ...
  connectedCallback() {
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.style.display = 'block';
    }, this.getAttribute('after'));
  }
  // ...
}
```

Finally let's add a method to programmatically display content:

```
class ShowContent extends HTMLElement {
  // ...
  display() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

We now have a fully fledged new html tag:

- Each instance manages its own business.
- Each instance can have its own delay.
- Each instance can be queried and styled.
- New instances can be added programmatically.
- The display can be programmatically triggered for each instance.

---

⚠️ *Please run this code with Chrome or Firefox; this is all based on standards but not all browsers are at the same level of their implementations*

```js
class ShowContent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const tmpl = document.querySelector('#show-content-template');
    const tmplContent = tmpl.content.cloneNode(true);
    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).appendChild(tmplContent);
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      this.style.display = 'block';
    }, this.getAttribute('after'));

  }
  display() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

customElements.define('show-content', ShowContent);

// manually trigger the display for this specific element
document.querySelector('#burrito').display();

// adding a new element programmatically
const chillies = document.createElement('show-content');
chillies.setAttribute('after', 4000);
chillies.innerHTML = '<p></p>';
document.body.appendChild(chillies);
```

```html
<template id="show-content-template">
  <style>
    :host {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <slot></slot>
</template>


<show-content after="1000">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</show-content>

<show-content after="2000">
  <p>Hello World!!</p>
</show-content>

<show-content after="3000">
  <p>Hello World!!!</p>
</show-content>

<show-content id="burrito" after="100000">
  <p></p>
</show-content>
```

Comment: Thanks but I wanted a way to extend an existing tag or the entire htmlelement class, not to make a new tag.

Comment: @Volper Up to you. This is just for your consideration in case you weren't aware of this option.

Comment: I actually saw this in another thread but decided to make my own because it's something else